# Who said 'Sacre Bleu?'

Tags: comics, character-identification

What comic book series had characters that said "Sacre Bleu"?

I am unable to find the title that seems right. I believe that the series was published in the early 1950's, possibly earlier.

Comment: "Sacre bleu" is an [old French expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrebleu), so it was probably used in a lot of different comics featuring French characters. And what is "the Aries"? Did you mean "the series"?

Comment: I have alwaysw anted to see a comic or tv or movie scene when Napoleon or another French officer recognizes advancing troops as Prusssian at the Battle of Waterloo and says:  "Sacre Blucher!  Its the Prussians!"

Comment: VTC as too broad because we don't know where the comics was from - if it's English-speaking it's something but if it was a Franco-Belgian one, pretty much _everything_ that's been published qualifies, even in the given timestamp.

Answer (score 6):

Although the phrase "sacré bleu" is said by pretty much every French-speaking character in the history of English language fiction, one who's particularly known for it is [André](https://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Andre_(Earth-One)), a member of the Blackhawks.

*Blackhawk* was a Quality Comics title first published in 1941 (under the *Military Comics* line), later sold to DC Comics; André himself was introduced in *Military Comics* #2, in September 1941, and was a member of the team until the New 52 reboot.

"Sacré bleu" is sort of André's catchphrase, since he's a French character in an American comic book in the 1940s and 50s:

[image]

[image]

Comment: ["said by pretty much every French-speaking character"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GratuitousFrench), is right. Gotta love stereotypes!

Answer (score 3):

Remy Lebeau, or Gambit, is a mutant superhero often featured in X-Men comics that comes from New Orleans, and often speaks French phrases, such as "Sacre bleu!". He is perhaps more well-known for phrases such as "Mon cheri", but his French-proficiency is often referenced in pop culture, such as in the title of this [article about a Gambit movie losing its director](http://www.scifinow.co.uk/news/gambit-movie-loses-its-director-sacre-bleu/).

While I'm still trying to source a comic where he says this (and I'm sure it exists), I have found other media.

One of the old school Genesis X-Men games has this line of dialogue:

> Gambit: Sacre bleu! Dis must be "Prof X" simulation of the savage. Let's have some fun, neh?

However, Gambit didn't make a first-appearance until 1990, although some of those 90s comics have an earlier feel to them.